# Remove a specific item in a list?

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I want to preface this by saying that yes, this is a homework problem I'm working on and I don't want the actual answer, just maybe a nudge in the right direction. Anyhoo, I'm taking a class on programming languages' structures, and one of our projects is to write a variety of small programs in lisp. This one requires the user to input a list and an atom, then remove all instances of the atom from the list. I've scoured the internet and haven't found all that many good lisp resources, so I'm turning to you all.

Anyways, our professor has given us *very little* by way of stuff to work off of, and by very little I mean practically nothing.

This is what I have so far, and it doesn't work.

```
(defun removeIt (a lis)
  (if (null lis) 0
      (if (= a (car lis))
          (delete (car lis))
          (removeIt (cdr lis)))))
```

And when I type 
`(removeIt 'u '(u e u e))`
as the input, it gives me an error stating it got 1 argument when it wanted 2. What errors am I making?

Answer (score 4):

First, a few cosmetic changes:

```
(defun remove-it (it list)
  (if (null list) 0
      (if (= it (car list))
          (delete (car list))
          (remove-it (cdr list)))))
```

Descriptive and natural sounding identifier names are preferred in the CL community. Don't be shy to use names like `list` – CL has multiple namespaces, so you don't have to worry about clashes too much. Use hyphens instead of camel case or underscores. Also, [read a short style guide.](http://dept-info.labri.fr/%7Estrandh/Teaching/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html)

You said you didn't want the answer but helpful tips, so here we go:

- Check your base case – your result will be a list, so why do you return a number?
- Use the appropriate comparison function – `=` is for numbers only.
- You are building a new result list, so no need to `delete` anything – just don't add to it what you don't want.
- But remember to add what you want – build your result list by `cons`ing what you want to keep to the result of applying your function to the rest of the list.
- If you don't want to keep an element, just go on applying your function to the rest of the list.
- You defined your function to take two arguments, but you're calling it with `(cdr list)` only. Provide the missing argument.

> I've scoured the internet and haven't found all that many good lisp
> resources,

Oh, come on.

Anyhow, I recommend [Touretzky.](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Edst/LispBook/book.pdf)

By the way, the function you're trying to implement is [built-in](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_rm.htm), but your professor probably won't accept it as a solution, and doing it yourself is a good exercise. (For extra credit, try solving it for nested lists.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for a recursive function. Suppose there exists already a function called my-remove which takes an atom and a list as arguments and returns the list without the given atom. So (my-remove 'Y '(X Y Z)) => '(X Z)
Now, how would you use this function when instead of the list '(X Y Z) you have another list which is (A X Y Z), i.e. with an element A in front?
You would compare A to your atom and then, depending on whether the element A matches your atom, you would add this element A or not to the result of applying remove to the rest of the list.
With this recursion the function my-remove will be called successively with shorter lists. Now you only have to think about the base case, i.e. what does the function my-remove have to return when the list is empty.

Answer (score -1):

This is an answer for other people looking specifically for elisp. A builtin function exists for this purpose called delq

Example

```
(setq my-list '(0 40 80 40 90))   ;; test list
(delq 40 my-list)                 ;; (0 80 90)
```

If you installed emacs from source you can check out how it is implemented by doing Mx find-function delq

Comment: Or just take a look at  `root/src/fns.c` (http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/fns.c) -- note that the implementation is not in lisp.

Comment: Note that you should `(setq my-list (delq 40 my-list))` instead, per [Elisp documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sets-And-Lists.html#index-delq).  To see this in action, try the answer's code, but delete `0` instead of `40`, and look at the value of `my-list` afterwards.